# Angular js Filter Highlight the first result

Tags: angularjs

I have an **ng-repeater** and **filter** in side of **diretive**, I would like to high light the first cell of the filtered data when start typing and filtered data appear. I have tried with **doucment.querySelect** select the first child but it didn't work i guess because the filter data is not ready yet, and first-child are still old data. is there anyway can get the first search result and add a class?

```
<textarea ng-model="keyword" ng-keydown="search($event)">

    <ul class="hint-list">
        <li ng-show="showPanel || (filtered.length > 0 && keyword.length > 0)" ng-repeat="option in filtered = (options | filter:keyword)" ng-click="appendOption(option, $index, $event)">{{option.name}}</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ng-repeat` exposes a `$first` variable](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) that you can use to apply a class (here, we assume the class `highlight` is the class you want to apply):

```
<ul class="hint-list" ng-class="{highlight: $first}">
  <li ng-show="showPanel || (filtered.length > 0 && keyword.length > 0)" ng-repeat="option in filtered = (options | filter:keyword)" ng-click="appendOption(option, $index, $event)">{{option.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/gazegizo/1/edit)

Comment: o Wow you saved me from all the headache, sorry i should pay attention on the api page -__- thanks heaps mate.

Comment: ofc in about 8 mins :)

Comment: Cheers, and happy JavaScripting!